im getting slow internet speed in ubuntu while in same pc i have windows10 as dualboot in that im getting 150 mbps
I'm getting Slow internet speed in ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS while in same pc i have windows10 as dual boot in that im getting 150 mbps.
My wifi adapter Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
My kernal version is Linux 6.8.0-41-generic
My device name - Dell Vostro 15 3568
Spec - Intel i5 7200u and ram 12gb

Does this answer your question?
